# angular2 how do I programmatic bootstrap?

Tags: angular

I am upgrading to RC6 and I need to programmatically bootstrap my application.  In the past I just called bootstrap from platform-browser-dynamic but it's gone now.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Since RC5, you don't bootstrap component anymore, you bootstrap module, like this:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

And your `app.module` should be something like this:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

For more info, check [Angular 2 Modules official docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html), as well as [RC4 to RC5 (basically RC6) Migration docs.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html)

Comment: I need to conditionally bootstrap.  My application need a service to run that determine the api URL.  Only after that runs do I want to bootstrap.  If I just wrap my app.component in an *ngIf i get routing errors because it hides the router-outel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a module. I followed this guide and succeeded:  https://www.barbarianmeetscoding.com/blog/2016/08/13/updating-your-angular-2-app-from-rc4-to-rc5-a-practical-guide/